# Can I replicate Spellwrought Tattoos with spells that are not on the Artificer's spell list?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, artificer, artificer-infusions

So through the *Replicate Magic Item* Infusion I'm able to replicate *Spellwrought Tattoos* (Cantrip/1st Level). But what if I have a level as a Wizard; can I replicate a tattoo with a 1st level wizard spell like *Find Familiar* for example? RAW it should be totally fine because Common Spellwrought Tattoos can be created using infusions. I know there are plenty of ppl out there that have a different opinion. But this question is not about whether you can replicate spell wrought tattoos in the first place, but if you can put every spell that you have prepared into them?

*Spellwrought Tattoos* pretty much work like scrolls IMO.
And for a scroll you have to have the particular spell prepared.

So it's RAW that I can give away familiars (Wizard spell)... with infusions or am I wrong?

### CLARIFICATION

I don't want a fundamental debate about spellwrought tattoos. Just imagine it could be RAI. What are the restrictions for that particular infusion?
I just ask that because my party assumes that those features work together. So it pretty much doesn't matter for the answer of my question if you think that the combo infusions/spell tattoos are a bug or RAI. I didn't ask you to answer that rather sensitive topic. Just assume that would work, because RAW it pretty much does... how would you manage it?

Comment: FWIW, I'm pretty sure the intent is that you can't replicate any consumable items. Potions and scrolls are mentioned specifically, but spellwrought tattoos are not, because they were published after the artificer rules.

Comment: You can use them in DnDBeyond, which is pretty much an indicator that it is RAI.
I just don't have the digital version of Tasha's so I can't check if those work with wizard spells.

Comment: @TheKhileyan The functionality of dnd beyond is not an indicator of anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123051/discussion-between-thomas-markov-and-thekhileyan).

Comment: I'm confused about your latest edit asking us to assume RAI. We generally can't assume intent and don't even really ask questions about that because of the difficulty of 'proving' it. Can you please clarify what you mean and if there is a starting ruling (houserule) that you want us to follow in assessing your question?

Comment: If you're sticking with this form of the question you need to update the title.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### RAW, you can do this, but it’s definitely an oversight.

You have correctly observed: spellwrought tattoos are very similar to spell scrolls. Replicate Magic Item says:

> Alternatively, you can choose the magic item from among the common magic items in the game, not including potions or scrolls.

You cannot replicate spell scrolls using the feature, and since spellwrought tattoos are also consumables that let you cast a spell once, it seems natural that they should be excluded as well. Based on this I would rule that you cannot replicate spellwrought tattoos.

As written, everything works as you have described, but it’s definitely a bug in the game. Technically it allows you to create a spellwrought tattoo *with any cantrip or 1st level spell*, even if you don’t know the spell. This doesn’t make sense, especially since it sort of overshadows your 11th level feature Spell Storing Item, which requires you store a spell you know.

#### The lack of clear rules for how this works is further evidence that it is an oversight.

*There are no rules for how this works*. Again, I must reemphasize that there are no rules restricting this use of the Artificer's Replicate Magic item. As written, the Artificer can replicate a spellwrought tattoo containing *any* cantrip or 1st level spell. It is abundantly obvious that this is not intended to be the function of the feature. So the best answer, in my estimation, to the question "what are the restrictions on this infusion?" is "don't allow the Artificer to create spellwrought tattoos with Replicate Magic Item."

*But I'm not your DM, so just ask yours*.

#### This bug was created by the publication of new material.

Prior to the publication of *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*, the only common magic items besides spell scrolls and potions were those found in *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*. Ergo, the Artificer's feature is definitively referring to this section. The publication of *Tasha's* created this bug by implementing a new type of common magic item consumable without accounting for it in the Replicate Magic Item feature description.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123056/discussion-on-answer-by-thomas-markov-can-i-replicate-spellwrought-tattoos-with). Let's continue it there :)

Comment: It may interest you to know that the original artificer could create magic items such as scrolls and wands of magic spells they didn’t know—in fact, that was largely the point of the class. Of course, that was also spelled out explicitly, and even though 3.5e was considerably higher-power than 5e, it still made the artificer one of the most overpowered classes in that system. But still, it maybe isn’t as outrageous as you make it out to be that an artificer could do that.

Comment: But spellwrought tattoos are a fundamentally different item than scrolls. I dont see why you should lump them in with scrolls. Its probably not actually an oversight

Comment: @DimitrisTz The designers have said in interviews the intention was to make an item like spell scrolls but allow non-casters to use it. Essentially a better version of spell scrolls with many of the requirements of the user removed. I would expect that they would errata this on the artificer side, but haven't heard of anything yet.
Frankly, both L1 scrolls and tattoos (or common potions) seem fine power wise except for maybe find familiar; or allowing summons or NPCs to use tattoos which really shouldn't be allowed, but /could/ be by a DM's interpretation.

Comment: On the other hand, Artficers were reprinted in the same sourcebook as Spellwrought Tattoos were introduced in, so if they wanted to close that loophole, they could have.

Answer (score 2):

RAW Yes you can.

I would rule based upon three things.

1. You are infusing an item with magic, thus you must have a base item first. In this case, a needle.
2. The wording of Spellwrought Tattoo that states, "To use the tattoo, you must hold the needle against your skin and speak the **command word**."  The user must be able to speak the command word, and apply the tattoo to themselves, and have knowledge of the command word.
3. Based upon the word **Replicate** itself. The artificer must first have knowledge of the item he/she wishes to replicate. Otherwise it is just invention.

Answer (score -1):

**RAW you cannot do this**, according to the first line of Infuse Item:

Infuse Item
"At 2nd level, you gain the ability to imbue mundane items with certain magical infusions. The magic items you create with this feature are effectively prototypes of **permanent items**."

Spell scrolls, potions, and certain tattoo needles are impermanent, they go away and never reappear. The Spell-Wrought Tattoo is one of these.

There is no oversight, just need to read up, not down.